# HyperV running but Hyperv Manager Cannot connect,

Tags: roles, hyper-v

ANy idea how to fix HyperV on Server 2019 standard
HOST in DOMAIN

**get-service *vmms***

Status   Name               DisplayName

---

Running  vmms               Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management

**get-vm**
get-vm : **Hyper-V has not been installed on computer 'HYPERV1'.**
At line:1 char:1

- get-vm
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unspecified,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

5VM are running normaly, start on reboot too, I can manage IT with PROHVM

It is possible to reinstall hyperV without Uninstall and Install (remove/add role?), 
strange is, that no errors in event logs

Tanks ..

- maybe some rights to check
- maybe some regedit key to import from another Server

Comment: SOP: Move VM's off, reinstall. See whether that fixes things. If not - start investigating what has been changed (group policy?)